# RegEx for segmenting a string

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I found this [Answer](https://superuser.com/a/666692) for how to paras movie names with RegExp, its working fine but not exactly what i need.

The input string is : `2001.A.Space.Odyssey.1968.720p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-LiNG.mkv`

The Regular Expression that used in the answer like this  :`^(.+).(\d{4}).+.(mp4|avi|mkv)$` and the [output](https://regex101.com/r/ZAyMQL/1) is:

```
2001.A.Space.Odyssey
1968
mkv
```

What i need is like the below :

```
2001.A.Space.Odyssey
1968
LiNG
mkv
```

My try was: `^(.+).(\d{4}).+([^_]).(mp4|avi|mkv)$` but the [output](https://regex101.com/r/Hfljd7/1) is:

```
2001.A.Space.Odyssey
1968
G
mkv
```

How i can get `LiNG` instead of `G` ?

Comment: Are you using Perl or something else?

Comment: Greediness + wrong pattern. Try `^(.+)\.(\d{4})[^-]*-(.*?)\.(mp4|avi|mkv)$`

Comment: There's no chance you are illegally sharing copywrite content, is there???

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i'm using freepascal

Comment: @revo it can be and answer :) it work great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression has four capturing groups:

```
(.+?)\.([0-9]{4}).+?-(.+)\.(mkv|avi|mp4)
```

where our desired outputs are.

The name of the movie is in the first capturing group:

```
(.+?)
```

followed by a `.` and the desired year in the second group:

```
([0-9]{4})
```

followed by everything else upto the last dash and here we are having the last word:

```
(.+)
```

and the desired extensions are in the last capturing group:

```
(mkv|avi|mp4)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ihwJd3/1)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /(.+?)\.([0-9]{4}).+?-(.+)\.(mkv|avi|mp4)/;
const str = `2001.A.Space.Odyssey.1968.720p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-LiNG.mkv`;
const subst = `$1\n$2\n$3\n$4`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

[image]